# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when trying to import VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I insert the following line at the top of my `src/main.js` file:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

I see the following error in the console:
[image]

I am using `"vue": "^2.6.11"`

This is what I see with `npm upgrade` command:

```
$ npm upgrade
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: chantorah_vue2@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^2.6.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.0.15
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-router
npm ERR!   vue-router@"^4.0.15" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/etayluz/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/etayluz/.npm/_logs/2022-06-04T20_22_08_025Z-debug.log
```

Why am I receiving this error? What is the proper way to import Vue Router into my vue.js project?

Comment: Try to `npm upgrade`. This looks like a Vue issue

Comment: @ext I think you are on to something. It looks like vue-router is not compatible with my version of vue. How do I get a vue-router version that is compatible with my vue version?

Comment: @etylauz https://v3.router.vuejs.org/installation.html#npm here are all the ways to install the needed version of vue-router

Comment: @ext I followed the installation guide which is just to run `npm install vue-router
` but this results in the same error above with the dependency. How do I resolve it? It seems like it installed the wrong version.

Comment: Try `npm remove vue-router`, and then `npm install vue-router@3.0`